# variables for an SFTP transfer script

Tags: linux, bash, backup, automation, sftp

I am attempting to do the following:

- export a database (maybe make a .tgz of it, that's trivial)
- pack up a whole tree into a .tgz
- copy both files into a named directory on a different server.

I *can* do all these things with the current script (bash) I have currently.
But as I am looking to automate things, I need more automation.

At the moment I

- make a directory with today's date
- mysqldump a database into a file with a name containing that date
- create a .tgz of a directory tree, again with a name containing today's date
- connect to a server via sftp (or scp, doesn't matter... it's a windows (s)ftp(s) server)
- upload a (currently static) file into a (currently static) directory
- exit the sftp server and spit out a status for the upload.

Do I turn the two filenames into variables before connecting to the sftp server, so that I can say "put $filename1" etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With any POSIX shell (and including `bash`) you can use commands such as these

```
# Today's date
today=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')

# Create directory
mkdir "$today"

# Dump SQL backup
mysqldump … > "$today/sqlbackup.$today.sql"

# Make a tarball
tar cf "$today.tgz" "$today"

# Transfer file
scp -p "$today.tgz" remoteHost:

# Get a status report from the immediately preceding command
echo "Status is $? (0=good)"
```

Comment: Thanks for reassuring me.
using the variable in the upload worked a charm.

Comment: @Bokkie not a problem